# Why I don't have any provisioning profiles in Devices menu of Xcode? How to fix this?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, provisioning-profile

I'm in the process of learning iOS development and app submission process. Before trying to archive my application I only tested and debug it on iOS 6 simulator and now I want to deploy this application on real device. And during this I encountered with some problems.

So, what steps I must implement in order to successfully archive my application and get an `.app` and then an `.ipa` file of it. How to setup provisioning profiles and solve code signing error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the provisioning portal at http://developer.apple.com and generate provisioning profiles for your applications there.

If you have not paid your developer license fee you will not be able to install your apps on real devices.

Comment: Ok. So there no  opportunities for trying to get .app file of my application and install it on real device?If even I don't want to load it on AppStore or iTunes?

Comment: The only other way to go is to jailbreak your device and use other, unsanctioned distribution techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get a Developer and or Distribution certificate including their respective Private keys. You will also need a Team Provisioning Profile, or a Provisioning Profile specifically made for the app. You can either make all these yourself through the provisioning portal at http://developer.apple.com  Or if you are working for someone else who has a developer program license, they could possibly provide you with all these.

The provisioning profile describes all the steps you need to take to implement the certificates and provisioning profiles so you can build and deploy / distribute your app.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm new to all this stuff.Earlier I developed for WinPhone and I get envolved in iOS development. And it's  a bit strange for me that if I want to develop a real physical app for iPhone I must pay for this if i don't even want to load it on appstore